# Not getting R.java file

Tags: android, r.java-file

I am not able to get back my `R.java` file after cleaning my project.

Please suggest me a solution which help me in this matter..

thanks in advance...

Comment: error show in res folder or src folder ?

Answer (score 2):

this can happen from one of two reasons:

1. you are not auto-rebuilding your project. (can be fixed in the settings).
2. you have a property within your project with and illegal name (such as files with capital letters).

fix this and the project will rebuild with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try building your project by selecting your project--> Build Project.

remove the Build Automatically setting from your projects tab of eclipse.

Try building them manually.

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse is not able to build R.java . There might be some problem in your xml layouts. Check them out.